# how to save a flex file?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I need to send a flex assigment...work on a "cart" using FlexBuilder 3.0 and send it to my instructor.

Do I save it as "Cart.mxml" or "cart.swf" so that she can open it in FlexBuilder and look at the code?

Which is the correct format?

Comment: Generally, the best thing to do in this case is ask the instructor what format they want it in.

Answer (score 1):

SWF is the final compile format. You'll want to send Cart.mxml (or Cart.as if you wrote it in straight ActionScript) because this is a source file that your instructor can compile into the SWF herself.

Comment: ok thank you Matt.
But when  i save it in .mxml file the file opening is facing problems.....right clik/open...does not show  flex.

Comment: @jil That has to do with _your_ computer settings, not an inherent fault in naming the file extension mxml. Your computer is just not currently set to open FlexBuilder when an MXML file is opened (which you can change using "Open with...").